# Aframe - How to detach THREE.Object3d from VR controller

Tags: three.js, aframe

I want to implement grabbable objects in A-Frame by attaching the THREE.object3d to the oculus quest 2 vr-controller. I manage to grab objects but not release them ( using the down and up trigger events) [Here's a snipe version of my code](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/sulky-jolly-actress).
Is there anything I am missing? It seems easy to do, but I cant figure how to return the grabbable object to the scene. Objects get stuck to the controller.

P.D : I dont want to use super hands, it adds more dependencies and it's breaking my code. Plus, it should be something easy to implement without adding external modules.